# Apache 2.4 compatibility with OpenSSL

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, mod-ssl

We run Apache HTTPD as a load balancer in production, using mod_ssl with OpenSSL. Whilst trying to compile the latest Apache version (2.4.41) we've hit problems with OpenSSL whilst building.

My question is, is there an official source for compatibility between OpenSSL and Apache HTTPD?

Apologies is I'm missing something simple here, but all I can find is the occasional mention of non-compatibility between various versions, rather than any definitive answer for what is tested and supported.

Comment: Clarifying what you mean by the phrase *we've hit problems with OpenSSL whilst building* would be helpful to include in your question.

Comment: Happy to do so, but that would involve a lot of ugly stack traces which really are not relevant to my question. My question was "Is there an official source for compatibility between OpenSSL and Apache HTTPD?". 

If there's a reason that the specifics of the problems would help clarify that question then I'm happy to post them, but it seems like it would add unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Edit your question to add which operating system and version, which httpd and openssl versions, and the compile errors you get.  mod_ssl has been used with every OpenSSL version for a long time on many platforms, they don't really bother documenting a specific version as a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Have raised it as a separate question and closed this one off. https://serverfault.com/q/987322/490730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the official source (there is normally an entry when a new version is supported or implemented [newest features]) and also if some version gets out of support.
https://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.4
Also You can find fixed bugs related to specific OpenSSL versions or features.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Sounds like what I'm looking for doesn't exist. I'll raise a separate question for the specific error I'm getting, as it doesn't sound like it is a compatibility issue.